# Publish G Suite Add-on: Deployment contains an empty host list

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to publish a Google Docs add-on and follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-gsuite-addons.

I see an error: "G Suite Add-ons Extension Deployment contains an empty host list."

My `appsscript.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Markua Support",
      "logoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/17jUOuZuoQzFBPXkIFkAF_iH0Ck32dUD3/view"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot with the error(s) I see.

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve that?

Comment: Here is the problem with your question for me. I am currently reading your question on my iPhone. So I can’t hover above your link to see if it’s a safe link. So I would recommend that you put everything in the question that you want in the question and don’t use external links. My feeling is that if you don’t want to take the time to write it then I probably don’t want to take the time to read it

Comment: You must show that you have ownership of a domain.  Do you own a domain name?  The instructions for verifying ownership of a domain are at: [https://support.google.com/a/answer/6248925?hl=en](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6248925?hl=en)  If you have a GSuite account see: [https://admin.google.com/ac/domains](https://admin.google.com/ac/domains)

Comment: @AlanWells Thank you, I checked and see that my domain is already verified. Maybe the screenshot I provided in my question gives a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: The "G Suite Add-ons Extension" shouldn't be checked.  You're trying to publish two different types of Add-ons using the same Google Cloud Platform project.  You need to use either one or the other.  If this is a Docs Add-on, then it's not an Extension.

Comment: "Under Extensions, check the G Suite Add-ons Extension checkbox." Copied from the documentation, clearly that's not good advice ;-). Thank you Alan, that fixed it. Feel free to provide this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's possible to check *both* the "G Suite Add-ons Extension" AND a checkbox under the "Editor Add-on Extensions" that will cause an error.  Both shouldn't be checked.  You need to use either one or the other. If this is a Docs Add-on, then it's not an Extension.